# Bitwise And and Bitwise or operations on a number

Tags: algorithm, recursion, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming

You are given an integer ***V*** with initial value set to ***0***. You are also given an array of distinct positive integers ***A*** with each ***A[i]*** less than  ***2 ^(20)*** .
You can do the following operation to ***V*** any number of times-
• Choose any element from ***A*** and set ***V*** to either ***V|A[i]***  or ***V&A[i]*** .

Our task is to tell how many ***distinct values V*** can take after **applying some amount of operations to V (possibly zero)**.

I tried this using recursion but failed to come up with any optimised approach. Kindly suggest some optimised approach.

Comment: Please share the suboptimal recursive solution that you tried so we can help improve it.

Comment: I tried using recursion generating all possible numbers recursively and then storing it a set to get all distinct values.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)